# Use Pocketsphinx Demo on Android with Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, pocketsphinx-android

I would like to test the Pocketsphinx Demo by from VCS, in Studio 2.3.1 I've clone the project using VCS/github with the project URL http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo

But when I run it the minimum SDK is 24 Is it possible to run it with an other SDK ? Because my phone is APi23.

Answer (score 0):

You can change 24 back to 23 and it will work, there is no strict requirements to use API level 24.